# SonarQube purge (LTS 5.6.1) takes ages for project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Every time a specific project runs its analysis, the purge db takes forever. The complete background task is about 11 minutes, of which usually 8-10 minutes are consumed by purge DB.

How can I avoid that the purge makes my analysis slow?

```
2017.03.24 14:58:05 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist tests | time=1187ms
2017.03.24 14:58:05 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist cross project duplications index | time=0ms
2017.03.24 14:58:37 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Enable snapshot | time=31542ms
2017.03.24 14:58:42 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Index components | time=5184ms
2017.03.24 15:06:14 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Purge db | time=452392ms
2017.03.24 15:06:14 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Apply permissions | time=47ms
```

Comment: To get more details about what's going on, you have the option of enabling TRACE logs (caution, performance impact inside) and have a look at which SQL requests are being very slow and/or done very often. Also, you should specify which SGBD you are using in your post (highly relevant to this mostly DB related step).

Answer (score 0):

The database was close to being full, after enlarging the database the backlog tasks went back from 14 minutes to 4 minutes. Will check on the trace logs just to make sure this is also the cause.